# PHP Spreadsheet data population wont pass column "Z"

Tags: php, laravel, phpspreadsheet

I'm using PHPSpreadsheet create and excel file  When I populate my data it wont pass column 'Z' when for this query my data actually have 81 column.

[image: Data population stops at column Z]

Below is my code :

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->getDefaultColumnDimension()->setWidth(19);
$sheet->getStyle('A:ZZ')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::HORIZONTAL_LEFT);
$sheet->getStyle('A:ZZ')->getAlignment()->setVertical(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\Alignment::VERTICAL_CENTER);
// $sheet->getStyle('A:U')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$sheet->getStyle('A1:ZZ1')->applyFromArray($headerStyleArray);
$sheet->getStyle('A:ZZ')->applyFromArray($fontArray);

// SET EXCEL HEADER &COLUMN WIDTH TO AUTOSIZE
$i=0;
foreach (range('A', $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $col) {
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
                    ->getColumnDimension($col)
                    ->setAutoSize(true);
        $sheet->getCell($col.'1')->setValue($header[$i]);
        if($i >= count($header)-1) {
            break;
        }
        $i++;
} 
// SET EXCEL CELL DATA
$rowNumber = 2;
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $i = 0;
    foreach (range('A', $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $char) {

        return response()->json($char.$rowNumber);
        if($i <= count($row)-1) {
            $sheet->getCell($char.$rowNumber)->setValue($row[$i]);
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $rowNumber++;
}

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $request->group_name. ' Member Attendance Report.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer->save('php://output');
return;
```

Any help is much appreaciated thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors, or any other clues at all. Did you look at the error log

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: my header & cell data array have all the data properly, theres no error or anything the issue here is the logic when drawing the data into the excel, the logic wont pass column 'Z'

Comment: `range()` won't create a proper set of entries past 'Z'.

Comment: so what can I do to solve this?

Comment: @M.Izzat Why do you do `return response()->json($char.$rowNumber);` in the for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
foreach (range('A', $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $col) {

}
```

to

```
$max_column = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn();
for($column = 'A'; !isBiggerExcelColumn($column,$max_column); ++$column){
    // rest of your code
}


function isBiggerExcelColumn($current_column,$max_column){
    if(strlen($current_column) < strlen($max_column)) return false;
    return strlen($current_column) > strlen($max_column) || strcmp($current_column,$max_column) > 0;
}
```

In the above, we make use of `++$column` to go to the next excel column that PHP provides for increment over strings. In `isBiggerExcelColumn()`, we do a string comparison using `strcmp` amd other length checks to judge if current column is greater than the max one. If yes, stop the loop, else continue;

Comment: so this part `->getColumnDimension($col)` should be replace with `->getColumnDimension($column)` correct?

Comment: @M.Izzat Yes, since `$column` is the local variable. You can change it to `$col` if you like in my code.

Comment: I did as follows and now it only display a single column

Comment: I add my code in the bottom of your answer, I will remove it later

Comment: @M.Izzat What do you get when you do `var_dump(count($headers))`?

Comment: @M.Izzat What do you get when you do `var_dump($max_column)` in your code?

Comment: my apologies, I made a mistake your code work perfectly, I accept it as the correct answer, thanks so much